# CSS problem with @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

So I'm front-end coding this flashy new start-up website and I am using a specific font. I am using @font-face, and the font shows in all browsers but some issues:

1) The font looks pixelated which makes it kinda ugly. This problem actually has happened to me before with other fonts so I will be happy if somebody recommends me how to get the font smooth.

2) In Opera and Safari the font renders normally (still pixelated) but in IE, Firefox and Chrome it renders bold, kinda bolder than normal. I tried putting font-weight but the font doesn't support any weight so it's normal. Any ideas on that problem ?

I really want this font and I can't understand how everybody is using font-face with all those rendering problems. I hope I am missing something.

Comment: My experience with using @font-face is that some fonts work better than others and ymmv with respect to how it appears in different browsers and on different platforms. I stick to a few fonts I've tested and like the appearance of across the relevant matrix. Time may improve the quality of some of the fonts.

Comment: yes, i am using windows since the back-end of the project will be on .net and i really think that problem is beyond my scope so i'm looking for a nice cross-browser font right now. thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what OS are you using since @font-face uses OS font rendering engine. On Windows XP just forget about getting it done right. Windows 7 does the job pretty much ok also in IE7/8.

One thing that can cause your fonts to look jagged can be the Cleartype options - turning it off fixes the edges since it won't do the extra anti-aliasing that is not needed since the embeded font is already anti-aliased.

One way to disable cleartype **on the client side** is to apply a IE specific `filter:` property (just use some simple property so it won't do anything except triggering the effect - like rotation by 0 degrees) to your headers in css - that causes IE to turn off cleartype to avoid conflicts between filter rendering and Cleartype rendering. But this will fix IE only.

There is also webkit specific `-webkit-font-smoothing` which works ok and might help you with chrome and css3 `font-smooth` (never used this one so can't tell you about results or supported browsers).

Most solid thing you could do, if you really want to keep your selected font, is to use [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) or similar font replacer. From my experience it does the job with an extra script load.

Overall for @font-face there is no solid solution to get it look the same on all browsers and systems.